# Untrusted URL error: accessing files from mobile file system in ionic 2

Tags: url, video, ionic2, filesystems

trying to run a video in iframe by setting the url from the mobile local file system on click of the file name, but getting the error of untrusted url even after using the sanitizer function, i am not getting how to deal with this, attached my error screenshot please find it.

[image: error screenshot]

also attached my code here, i dont know where i am going wrong. Please help.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {DomSanitizer,SafeResourceUrl,} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Generated class for the Nextpage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-nextpage',
  templateUrl: 'nextpage.html',
})


export class Nextpage {

 
   iframepath: string;
   trustedUrl: SafeResourceUrl;
    
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    this.iframepath=navParams.get('path');
 
 this.trustedUrl = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.iframepath);
 
 //this.iframepath = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.ionicframework.ionic2992319/files/dizzy.mp4';
 //this.trustedUrl = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.iframepath);
 
 console.log("trustedUrl "+this.trustedUrl);
 }
  
   
   
    goBack(){
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
   
   
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Nextpage');
  }

}
```

this is trusted url used in the html file`<iframe width="100%" height="300" [src]="trustedUrl"></iframe>`